# Get user input within range while handling exceptions

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to get a user to input a number between 1 and 6 inclusive, and also handle if they put in a non integar. Here is my code below so far but cant seem to get it to work right. I have tried everything I can with exceptions, try and if else statements within the function but no luck getting it to work :( help please. I got part of it to work but when I ask for them to enter the number again I don't know how to code it right so the exceptions keep working. I took the exceptions out because none of them worked. Thanks in advance

```
user_choice = int(input("Enter your choice: "))

if user_choice <= 6 and user_choice >= 1:
    return user_choice

else:
    print("Invalid menu option.")
    user_choice = int(input("Please try again: "))
    return user_choice
```

Comment: What are you returning user_choice to? Return is used to return something from a function - try printing instead.

Comment: to another function, I know the code works, it is just that it doesn't handle exceptions which it needs to for eg, if the user enters in a letter, it needs to ask again also. if i enter k it just gives a python error. i need it to say invalid menu option and ask the user to try again.

Answer (score 0):

```
user_choice = input("Enter your choice: ")

try:
    user_int = int(user_choice)
except ValueError as e:
    # user didn't enter an integer!
    print("Please enter an integernext time")

if user_choice <= 6 and user_choice >= 1:
    print(user_choice)
```

This should illustrate try / except clauses.

Comment: The OP wants to try/except a ValueError

Comment: Oh yeah, I modified it.

Comment: Thank you Andrew, its not nice getting a -1 when the person giving it doesn't read my question correctly........

Comment: thank you Danielle. Hope I made sense!. This works but I need it to ask again and again without re running the program. thanks again

Comment: When does a string equal an integer?

Comment: ive modified it more but seems to just ask once for the choice, then if i enter a letter again it just give a python error not the error "invalid menu option" then to ask again for an input.